# Brightness on one of dual screen monitors keeps lowering

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, brightness

I have a dual screen setup on an HP Pro 3300 (Pentium G620 2.6GHZ, 3GB RAM, 500GB HDD) running Windows 7 Professional x64 and using a ATI Radeon HD 5450 (both monitors are connected to the GFX Card, not the on-board Graphics), the monitors are both Samsung SyncMaster 723N's (17" LCD's). Basically a couple of months ago I noticed the brightness on the left hand monitor had gone darker than the right. I fiddled with settings in "Calibrate Display Colour" in the Control Panel and got the brightness back to matching the other screen. A few weeks later the same thing happened, the left hand screen was darker than the right so again I changed some settings and all was well. But it's happened today for a third time and I was wondering really if anyone could advise as to what might be causing this? I've tried replacing the monitor but that didn't seem to help. It's obviously a relatively trivial issue, but it's most annoying!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the value in your controlpanel actually changes? for all we know your monitor is dying.

Comment: I'm not sure, it's just like a config wizard I've been using where you say - that looks right, yeah that looks ok, etc. As above though, initially I assumed it was a hardware issue and replaced with another monitor only to see the same problem. Which is when I put the original monitor back and started playing with the control panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the onboard settings of the individual monitor you want to adjust and change the brightness/contrast/gamma to your desired settings.

**Don't** use the Graphics card's control panel settings through the operating system.

Comment: Ridiculous question I'm sure but - how would I access the "onboard settings" of the monitor? Do you mean using the buttons on the actual monitor to adjust brightness, etc or is this something I can access in Windows?

Comment: Yes, I mean the buttons on the monitor. Once you set those, **don't** press "calibrate..." anymore, as this will reset your setting.